# gcsfuse terminating itself on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcsfuse

I have gcsfuse in a deployment on GKE, it was working fine and without any changes in the config it started failing since yesterday.

```sh
Received signal 15; terminating.
```

I have it deployed in 2 different clusters, first I thought it was related to the kubernetes version because I started to see the issue when upgraded to `1.17.14-gke.1200`, but in the other cluster I still have `1.17.14-gke.400` and both have same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem, I was using the command as follows `gcsfuse -o nonempty --implicit-dirs...`, when I removed the `-o nonempty` flag it started working.

The strange thing is that it was working just fine until 2 days ago, suddenly that stopped working.

I decided to try without that after reading this:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#mount8-and-fstab-compatibility